# Static form to print on TPL

Tags: 7, forms, theming

I have created a module i can use to create multiple blocks, now with one of those blocks, there is a requirement for a form (which the user needs to be able to see). However, this does not require any Drupal "Save" interactions.

Its a very simple static form that is manipulated with Ajax functionality. I have just coded this form simply within the TPL file.

```
<form name="formelement" method="post">
    <input name="data" type="hidden" value="" />
    <div class="something_here">something here</div>
    <div class="something_here">something there</div>
    <input required="" type="text" class="" name="blah1">
    <input required="" type="text" class="" name="blah">
    <div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn" href="">submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Question** - I need to be able to get the $_POST in a function - what would be the best method of creating this form with the .module file or the drupal 7 api and then print it within the tpl file

Answer (score 0):

You can create form by develop custom module then you use developed form any where in node or block.

**Create a custom module**

- Create a file sites/all/modules/own/form_test/f**orm_test.info**
- Create a file sites/all/modules/own/form_test/**form_test.module**

(start it with `<?php` tag, but don't add ending `?>` tag)

```
function form_test_form($form,&$form_submit) {
  $form['firstname'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Firstname'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['lastname'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Lastname'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
  );
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#value' => 'Submit',
    '#type' => 'submit',
    );
  return $form;
}
```

More [details](http://www.wdtutorials.com/how-to-create-forms-drupal-tutorial/7#.VkWh47crIdU)

Comment: thanks for that information. When looking into the details page that you posted, it stated that the new page is being created with the menu hook. How can i call it within an existing template but have a callback functionality.